# ¿Como realizar un formulario con archivo adjunto multiple php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

tengo una pequeña falla en mi sistema de formulario, quiero enviar varios archivo al correo, pero solo envia 1 archivo, mi formulario, me pueden ayudar a como ponerle adjunto multiple sin falla, se los agradecería.

```
    <?php

class Email {
    
    //nombre
    var $nombre;
    //email del emisor
    var $mail;
    //email del receptor
    var $mailr;
    var $asunto;                    
    //archivo adjunto
    var $adjunto;
        //archivo adjunto
        var $adjunt;
        //mensaje
        var $msn;
        //mensaje
        var $msn1;
        //mensaje
        var $msn2;
        //mensaje
        var $msn3;
        //mensaje
        var $msn4;
        //mensaje
        var $msn5;
        //mensaje
        var $msn6;
        //mensaje
        var $msn7;      
        //mensaje
        var $msn8;
        //mensaje
        var $msn9;  
        //mensaje
        var $msn10; 
    //enviar el mensaje
    private $sender;}
    //url para redireccionar
    private $url;

    //función constructora
    public function __construct(){
        //cada uno de ellos es el parámetro que enviamos desde el formulario
        $this->nombre = $n;
        $this->mail = $m;
        $this->mailr = $mr;
        $this->asunto = $a;                             
        $this->msn = $msn;
        $this->msn = $msn1;
        $this->msn = $msn2;
        $this->msn = $msn3;
        $this->msn = $msn4;
        $this->msn = $msn5;
        $this->msn = $msn6;
        $this->msn = $msn7;
        $this->msn = $msn8;
        $this->msn = $msn9;
        $this->msn = $msn10;
        $this->adjunto = $ad;
        $this->adjunt = $adt;       
    }

    //método enviar con los parámetros del formulario
    public function enviar($n,$m,$mr,$a,$ms,$msn1,$msn2,$msn3,$msn4,$msn5,$msn6,$msn7,$msn8,$msn9,$msn10,$ad,$adt){
        //si existe post
        if(isset($_POST)){

    //si existe adjunto
    if($ad) {
        //añadimos texto al nombre original del archivo
        $dir_subida = 'fichero_';
        //nombre del fichero creado -> fichero_nombreArchivo.pdf
        $fichero_ok = $dir_subida . basename($ad);
        //y lo subimos a la misma carpeta
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name'], $fichero_ok);
    }

            //creamos el mensaje
            $contenido = '
                <h2>Appointments Ticket: '.$n.'</h2>
                <hr>
                Email: <b>'.$m.'</b><br>
                Problem: <br><b>'.$msn.'</b><br>
                Solution: '.$msn1.'</b><br>
                CPE model: <br><b>'.$msn2.'</b><br>
                Antenna model:'.$msn3.'</b><br>
                Tower options: <br><b>'.$msn4.'</b><br>
                CPE gain set (Cambium and Mimosa radios only): '.$msn5.'</b><br>
                CPE frequency all check (Cambium radios only): '.$msn6.'</b><br>
                CPE surge suppressor: '.$msn7.'</b><br>
                CPE bonded: '.$msn8.'</b><br>
                CPE service loop / Drip loop: '.$msn9.'</b><br>
                Vistabeam recommended firmware / radio - router: '.$msn10.'</b><br>
            ';
            //archivo necesario para enviar los archivos adjuntos
            require_once 'AttachMailer.php';

            //enviamos el mensaje           (emisor,receptor,asunto,mensaje)
            $this->sender = new AttachMailer($m, $mr, $a, $contenido);
            $this->sender->attachFile($fichero_ok);

            //eliminamos el fichero de la carpeta con unlink()
            //si queremos que se guarde en nuestra carpeta, lo comentamos o borramos
            unlink($fichero_ok);
            //enviamos el email con el archivo adjunto
            $this->sender->send();
                        //enviamos el email con el archivo adjunto
                        $this->sender1->send();
            //url para redireccionar
            $this->url = 'http://getdiscoverit.com/demo/';
            //redireccionamos a la misma url conforme se ha enviado correctamente con la variable si
            header('Location:'.$this->url.'?s=si');
        }
        else{
            //redireccionamos a la misma url conforme NO se ha enviado correctamente con la variable no
            header('Location:'.$this->url.'?s=no');
        }
    }
}

//llamamos a la clase
$obj = new Email();
//ejecutamos el método enviar con los parámetros que recibimos del formulario
$obj->enviar($_POST['nombre'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['emailr'], $_POST['asunto'], $_POST['msn'], $_POST['msn1'], $_POST['msn2'], $_POST['msn3'], $_POST['msn4'], $_POST['msn5'], $_POST['msn6'], $_POST['msn7'], $_POST['msn8'], $_POST['msn9'], $_POST['msn10'], $_FILES['adjunto']['name'], $_FILES['adjunt']['name1']);

?>



html

        <li>
                        <label for="adjunto">Archivo adjunto</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="file" id="adjunto" name="adjunto">
                    </li>
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu problema o error en concreto? Y, si usas alguna API o biblioteca (como PHPMailer) conviene que lo menciones y pongas su etiqueta en la pregunta.

Comment: utiliza un envio directo a correo los sms el problema que tengo es que quiero en adjutar archivos que pueda enviar varios a la vez no uno solo